# User registration form change Username to name

Tags: drupal-7, user-registration

I want to change the label of a registration form from 'Username' to name. I had used 'String overrides' module. But its not effecting. Is there any way out. please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement your custom module and alter the registration form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MyMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['account']['name']['#title'] = 'YOUR REPLACED VALUE'; //Username default
}
```

MyMODULE is your custom module name.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the permanent change than you can got to

> modules/user/user.module

under

> function user_account_form

line number 1033 change the title to

> '#title' => t('Name')

Comment: For people now reading this: You should never hack the core modules. The best reason for that is that you can't do security updates without overwriting your changes. (Also not hacking core is best-practice.) See more: https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core